# Knockout Checkboxes using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js

Context: I have a table with a list of checks. Each check has a checkbox and the table itself has a "select all" check box at the top.  The purpose for the check boxes is to print the checks.

I currently have the select all check box working - it adds all of the checks to a chosenChecks ko.observable array as well as the checkIDs to a CheckIDs array.  The server's print function uses a list of checkIDs.

The issue I am having is with the adding and removing of individual checks/checkIDs.. I'm not sure how to determine if the check/checkID is already in the array, and if so, how to remove it. Here's the code, with the views etc.

Disclaimer: I might be over thinking this in how I've setup all of my arrays.

Thanks for all your help.

The View:

```
 <table class="details_table" data-bind="visible: vendorChecks().length">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Check ID
            </th>
            <th>Check Date
            </th>
            <th>Vendor Name
            </th>
            <th>Check Amount
            </th>
            <th>Approve Status
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectAllChecks" title="Select all/none"/>
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="nohighlight" data-bind="foreach: $root.vendorChecks">
        <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="text: $data.CheckID"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: CheckDate"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: VendorName"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: FormatCurrency(CheckAmount())"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: Globalize.formatCheckRunApproveStatus(ApprovalStatusID())"></span></td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="print_line_checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.chosenChecks(), click: $root.addCheck"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The Typescript:

```
 class SearchPrintedChecksModel {
    public checkRuns = ko.observableArray<CheckRunModel>(null);
    public bankDrafts = ko.observableArray<BankDraftInfoModel>(null);
    public vendorChecks = ko.observableArray<BankDraftInfo>(null);
    public isSelectedCheck = ko.observable(false);
    public chosenChecks = ko.observableArray<BankDraftInfo>(null);
    public checkIDs = ko.observableArray();

    public addCheck(checkIDs) {
        var checks = printModel.chosenChecks();
        const CheckIDs = checkIDs;
        for (var i in checks) {
            checkIDs.push(checks[i].CheckID);
            ???
        }
    }
    public selectAllChecks = ko.pureComputed({
        read: function () {
            return this.chosenChecks().length === this.vendorChecks().length;
         },
        write: function(value) {
            this.chosenChecks(value ? this.vendorChecks.slice(0) : []);
            const checks = printModel.chosenChecks();
            const checkIDs = printModel.checkIDs();
            for (let i in checks) {
                if (checks.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    printModel.checkIDs.push(checks[i].CheckID);
                }
            }
            this.addCheck(checkIDs);
        },
        owner: this
    });

}


$(document).ready(() => {
    ko.applyBindings(printModel);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than finding the error in your logic, I'd suggest looking in to a slightly different structure:

- Put a `checked` observable in each of the items. Use this observable in the `checked` data-bind.
- Create a `computed` with a `read` and `write` method in the parent view model.

  - The `read` function checks if *all* items are checked
  - The `write` function passes the written value to *each* item

Here's what the code would look like:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  
  this.items = [
    { id: 1, checked: ko.observable(false) },
    { id: 2, checked: ko.observable(false) },
    { id: 3, checked: ko.observable(false) },
    { id: 4, checked: ko.observable(false) },
  ];
  
   this.allChecked = ko.computed({
     read: function() {
       return this.items.every(function(item) {
         return item.checked();
       });
     },
     write: function(value) {
        this.items.forEach(function(item) {
          item.checked(value);
        });
     }
   }, this);
}
    
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: allChecked">
  all
</label>
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checked"/>
      <span data-bind="text: 'Item ' + id"></span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I updated my code to reflect a similar structure, however it's telling me that vendorChecks object doesn't support every.  I am using Typescript. Not sure if that' makes a difference.

Comment: `Array.prototype.every` might be too "new" for Typescript. Not sure.. Here's the polyfill and support table: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Polyfill

Comment: I did actually figure it out based on the suggestion you provided, so I'll mark it as answered.  Thank you